# How can I get jquery slideshow to resize to 100% width when I resize browser?

Tags: jquery, css

I have a jquery slideshow in my website. Each slide has a width of 100% using css width:100%. Within each slide is a separate div which with a width of 1160px and margin:0 auto to centre it within the slide. The slides each have a different background image that is centred so it bleeds off the edges of the slide.

It all seems to be working fine with the images and navigation postioned correctly within the slide until I resize the browser window. When I do this the slides seem to retain the initial width from when the page loaded. When I refresh the slides re-centre and everything goes back into postion.

How can I make the slides stay 100% width without having to refresh the page each time i resize the window?

Comment: $(window).resize(function() {});

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [`$(window).resize(function(e) { /* do re-sizing work */ })`](http://api.jquery.com/resize/)

To further extend:

I have to first say, there's not much reason 100% width on your div shouldn't work unless the width is being reset dynamically somewhere else, or if the parent has a set width.

But if you must have a jQuery example of just One way it could be done (there are many), here ya go:

```
//  simple way to start jQuery, similar to `window.onload = function(event) {`
$(function() {
    //  Establish a simple timer var to make sure code doesnt run like a wild hamster on sesame seed oil
    var tmrResize;
    //  jQuery way to call `window.onresize = function(event) {`
    $(window).resize(function(e) {
        //  simply clear timer, no need for if statement, if it's undefined, its cleared
        clearTimeout(tmrResize);
        //  set timer for 1/4 of a second which outa be enough time to know someone is done resizing a window,
        //  the longer the timer, the more glitchy it will appear in the end
        //  and fyi, i see alot of people shorten timers by replacing the function call,
        //  example (   setTimeout(myFunction, 250);    )
        //  i can tell ya from experience, such method is not "cross-browser" friendly
        //  just simply put your function, if external, inside the function call
        tmrResize = setTimeout(function() {
            //  jQuery standard similar to document.getElementsByTagName("div").style.width = screen.width
            $("div").width($(document).width());
        }, 250);
    });
});
```

See Also:

- [What does "width: 100%" do in CSS?](http://www.impressivewebs.com/width-100-percent-css/)
- [.ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)
- [.resize()](http://api.jquery.com/resize/)
- [.width()](http://api.jquery.com/width/)

Comment: Thanks SpYk3HH

Almost there with that. It works on resize and when the page is loaded but for some reason each subsequent slide seems to "forget" it's supposed to be full width. I think I need to get the resize function to execute each time the cycle function is executed so that each slide is resized when it is loaded.